# Error propagation through recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

I want to see how the error propagates on a mapping that I have. I have proven that $$|f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)|=\varepsilon(1+\varepsilon),$$
let $\varepsilon_n$ be the error after $n$ applications of the mapping, it holds $\varepsilon_{n+1}=\varepsilon_n(1+\varepsilon_n)$.
It is easy to show $\varepsilon_n$ obeys
$$\frac{\varepsilon_n}{\varepsilon_0}=\sum_{k=0}^{2^n} p_k(n) \varepsilon_0^k$$
with $p_k(n)$ polynomials. I have convinced myself that $p_k(n)$ is of degree $k$ and the coefficient of the highest order term is 1, which by the way is exactly what I need. However I cannot find how to prove it. I even have difficulties setting up an induction.

So, first of all, is this by any chance a known map? Can I find any results anywhere? Also any idea on how to prove this is more than welcome.

EDIT: Motivation

The motivation comes from trying to approximate the separatrices of a map. So I have a map $f:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2$ and let $w(s)$ be a separatrix parametrised by $s\in\mathbb{C}$ for which it holds $f(w(s))=w(s+1)$.

The problem is that I know $w(s)$ as an approximation by a formal series $w_N(s)=\sum_{i=1}^N w_i s^{-i}$ I also know that the error is of the order of $s^{-N}$.

I try to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(w_N(s-n))=w(s)$$
this is possible because the error is not constant with $n$, for big $n$ the error is of the order $n^{-N}$ and if the error propagates as expected, then it goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$\frac{\varepsilon_n}{\varepsilon_0}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k, n) \varepsilon_0^k$$
where $f(k, n)$ is your $p_k(n)$.

Note that 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k, n+1) \varepsilon_0^k=\frac{\varepsilon_{n+1}}{\varepsilon_0}& =\frac{\varepsilon_n(1+\varepsilon_n)}{\varepsilon_0} \\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k, n) \varepsilon_0^k\right)\left(1+\varepsilon_0\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k, n) \varepsilon_0^k\right) \\
& =\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k, n) \varepsilon_0^k\right)+\varepsilon_0\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k, n) \varepsilon_0^k\right)^2 \\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k, n) \varepsilon_0^k\right)+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} f(j, n)f(k-1-j, n)\right)\varepsilon_0^k\right)
\end{align}

Thus $$f(k, n+1)=f(k, n)+\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} f(j, n)f(k-1-j, n)\right)$$

*Note: This equation holds $\forall n,k \in \mathbb{Z}, n, k \geq 0$. In the following proof by strong induction, there is no restriction on $n$. Any equation with $n$ is assumed to hold for all non-negative integers $n$.*

We now prove by strong induction on $k$ that $f(k, n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k$ with leading coefficient $1$.

The above equation implies $f(0, n+1)=f(0, n)$ (the 2nd term with the sum is empty), so by induction $f(0, n)=1 \, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \geq 0$.

Suppose that the statement holds for $0 \leq k \leq l$. Then by the induction hypothesis, 
$f(i, n)f(l-i, n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ with degree $l$ and leading coefficient $1 \, \forall i$, so $f(l+1, n+1)-f(l+1, n)=\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{l} f(i, n)f(l-i, n)\right)$ is a polynomial in $n$ with degree $l$ and leading coefficient $(l+1)$. Thus there exists $a_0, a_1, \ldots , a_{l-1}$ such that 
$$f(l+1, n+1)-f(l+1, n)=(l+1)!\binom{n}{l}+\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}{a_i\binom{n}{i}}$$

*Note: To see why this is true, note that both $f(l+1, n+1)-f(l+1, n)$ and $(l+1)!\binom{n}{l}$ are polynomials in $n$ with degree $l$ and leading coefficient $l+1$, so their difference is a polynomial in $n$ with degree $\leq (l-1)$. Any polynomial $P(n)$ can be written as a linear combination of binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{i}$, where $0 \leq i \leq deg(P(n))$, so in particular the above equation holds for some $a_i$.*

Thus 
\begin{align}
f(l+1, n)& =f(l+1, 0)+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{(f(l+1, j+1)-f(l+1, j))} \\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{(f(l+1, j+1)-f(l+1, j))} \\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{\left((l+1)!\binom{j}{l}+\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}{a_i\binom{j}{i}}\right)} \\
& =(l+1)!\binom{n}{l+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}{a_i\binom{n}{i+1}}
\end{align}

*Note:$f(l+1, 0)=0$ since $l+1 \geq 1$ and $1=\frac{\varepsilon_0}{\varepsilon_0}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k, 0) \varepsilon_0^k$.*

This is indeed a polynomial in $n$ of degree $l+1$ and leading coefficient $1$.

We are thus done by strong induction.

Comment: I am a bit lost at the line
$$f(l+1, n+1)-f(l+1, n)=(l+1)!\binom{n}{l}+\sum_{i=0}^{l-1}{a_i\binom{n}{i}}$$
how did $(l+1)!\binom{n}{l}$ appear?
And maybe a silly question but how do we know that such $a_i$'s exist?

Comment: Both $f(l+1, n+1)-f(l+1, n)$ and $(l+1)!\binom{n}{l}$ are polynomials with degree $l$ and leading coefficient $l+1$. Thus their difference is a polynomial with degree $\leq (l-1)$. Now every polynomial of degree $d$ can be written as a linear combination of binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{i}$, where $0 \leq i \leq d$ e.g. $n^3=6\binom{n}{3}+6\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}$. Thus we can write $f(l+1, n+1)-f(l+1, n)-(l+1)!\binom{n}{l}$ as $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{l-1}{a_i\binom{n}{i}}$ for some $a_i$.

Comment: Oh! ok, I can see that is a polynomial of degree $l$ and leading coefficient $l+1$ so we have $(l+1)(l!\binom{n}{l})=(l+1)!\binom{n}{l}$. My other problem is that I cannot see how the following equation appears
$$f(l+1, n)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{(f(l+1, j+1)-f(l+1, j))}$$
Also does your proof hold when $n>l$ or is it more general?

Comment: I think I skipped a step there. Note: $f(l+1, n)=f(l+1, 0)+(f(l+1, 1)-f(l+1, 0))+(f(l+1, 2)-f(l+1, 1))+ \ldots + f(l+1, n)-f(l+1, n-1))=f(l+1, 0)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}{(f(l+1, j+1)-f(l+1, j))}$ Now $f(l+1, 0)=0$ so you get that equation.

Comment: There is no restriction on $n$. The equation $$f(k, n+1)=f(k, n)+\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} f(j, n)f(k-1-j, n)\right)$$ holds for all $n, k$. I will edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I find your proof amazing. I had no chance to come up with it. Just a something a bit more general that bothers me. I can see why $n^3=6\binom{n}{3}+6\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}$, but what happens when for example $n=2$ or when $n=1$?

Comment: Oh well, I just figured out that it still works! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but $\epsilon_{n + 1} = \epsilon_n (1 + \epsilon_n)$ diverges (if $\epsilon_n > 0$ then $1 + \epsilon_n > 1$, and $\epsilon_{n + 1} > \epsilon_n$).

Comment: Well yes, but I don't see how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: It makes the question moot? If the error tends to $\infty$, there is no point in the approximation scheme.

Comment: No, check the question, I updated it.